# Changing the postion of div relatively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 16 divs in my page and every div has a cross button on top right, on click of cross button that div should be hidden and the div which is next to hidden div should be re positioned, for example suppose we have 5 div

1 2 3 4 5

suppose 3 is crossed the sequence should be like

1 2 4 5.

there is one more button in divs which is like button, onclick of that button, that div should come to position 1 for example we have 10 divs like :

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0

say 8 is liked then layout should be like:

8 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 9 0

Comment: So, what's the question? :/

Comment: The part where it smells like "do my homework for me" is that I get the sense you haven't even actually built the pre-behavior page yet. So floated or inline divs and you want to remove or remove and prepend them. Those are the names of the two jquery methods you need, by the way. "remove" and "prepend". I also gave you the two exact CSS terms you should google if the CSS eludes you.

Comment: I am new to JQ so i had no idea about that ... and i've done my home work i thought it will look like crap here... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float your divs. When one is hidden, the rest will automatically move.

As for the repositioning, you need to move them around with jQuery.

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaMsP/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">1<br/><a class="like" href="#">Like me</a></div>
    <div class="box">2<br/><a class="like" href="#">Like me</a></div>
    <div class="box">3<br/><a class="like" href="#">Like me</a></div>
    <div class="box">4<br/><a class="like" href="#">Like me</a></div>
    <div class="box">5<br/><a class="like" href="#">Like me</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.box { 
    display: block; 
    width: 90px; 
    height: 50px; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('a.like').on('click', function () {
    $('#container').prepend($(this).parent());
    return false;
})

$('div.box').on('click', function() {
   $(this).hide();
})
```

Comment: this is the exact thing i want, thanks a lot man.. but i want some JQ animation effects.. what needs to be doen for that

Comment: Well you need to research on animation... like fadeOut() instead of hide(). Depends on the animation you want. If you want your div to visually move to the first position they that's a whole different story on CSS and everything. Come back when you have tried some stuff and accept the answer if it answered your question... which it did.

Comment: I've got the answer... thnx a lot :)

Comment: as I am new to JQ.. could you please tell me what needs to be weitten in head part.. i am writing this

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.0"></script>
  

<script type="text/javascript" src="click.js"></script>' 

'click.js is the file in which im writing your code'

Comment: What you have now should work except that you need to add http:// to the url of the jquery file.